# Running default eventhub function returns "unexpected status code: 400"

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Running the basic azure function template for "Azure Event Hub trigger":

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(event: func.EventHubEvent):
    logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                 event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

I'm getting `unexpected status code: 400` when executing the function locally in VSC.
I've got local functions running:
[image]
And confirmed the EH instance name is correct in my `function.json`

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "homeeventhub",
      "connection": "",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

The full log error:

```
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.401Z] Executing HTTP request: {
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.403Z]   requestId: "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.404Z]   method: "GET",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.406Z]   userAgent: "ms-rest-js/2.6.0 Node/v16.14.2 OS/(x64-Windows_NT-10.0.22000) vscode-azurefunctions/1.8.3",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.407Z]   uri: "/"
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.408Z] }
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.511Z] Executed HTTP request: {
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.512Z] Executing HTTP request: {
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.514Z]   requestId: "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.512Z]   requestId: "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.515Z]   method: "POST",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.516Z]   identities: "",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.517Z]   userAgent: "ms-rest-js/2.6.0 Node/v16.14.2 OS/(x64-Windows_NT-10.0.22000) vscode-azurefunctions/1.8.3",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.518Z]   status: "200",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.518Z]   uri: "/admin/functions/ehtest2"
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.519Z]   duration: "108"
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.520Z] }
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.520Z] }
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.599Z] Executing StatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 400
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.603Z] Executed HTTP request: {
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.604Z]   requestId: "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.605Z]   identities: "(WebJobsAuthLevel:Admin, WebJobsAuthLevel:Admin)",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.606Z]   status: "400",
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.606Z]   duration: "91"
[2022-11-02T23:14:53.607Z] }
```

I'm sure it's just some kind of local configuration but I don't know what else I can troubleshoot. I have an additionall HTTP function that is running fine locally. Is there something else in the config that needs to be set up?

Comment: Hi @billmanH - The Folder Structure section of the Azure Functions docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#folder-structure) mention "not all options are supported when running [the `host.json` file] locally". The `local.settings.json` file is used to store app settings and connection strings locally. Do you have this `local.settings.json` file set up as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ensure you have all the configuration settings configured properly such as:**

**function.json:**

```
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
{
"type": "eventHubTrigger",
"name": "event",
"direction": "in",
"eventHubName": "kdemoeventhub",
"connection": "krisheventhubns_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB",
"cardinality": "many",
"consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

`krisheventhubns_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB` is the Azure Event Hub Namespace Connection string available in Shared access policies of the Azure portal Event Hub Namespace.

**local.settings.json:**

```
{

"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
"krisheventhubns_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB": "<Your-Event-Hub-NS-ConnStr"
}
}
```

[image]

- To run the Azure Functions Python Event Hub Trigger, you need to pass/send some events so that you can observer the default function is capturing and logging the events.
- Create `Sender.py` file and get the send events code from this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send) of send events to Azure Event Hub using Python.
- Then run the Azure Functions Project using the terminal code `func host start` or Run > Run without debugging. Once the host is initialized, then run the sender.py file with the cmdlet `python send.py` and then observe the events in Azure portal Event Hub:
  [image]

Comment: This makes sense. So the "execute function locally" button in VSC doesn't manually send an eventhub message. You need to turn it on and then use the sender to trigger it. Is that the propper pattern?

Comment: Yes, That's Correct @billmanH! You need to write the code for sending and receiving the events so that Event Hub will track all those events!

Comment: That explains why the log references an HTTP request/response. I thought that was odd given that this is an EH trigger and not a HTTP. I'll try this out.

Comment: Tested and confirmed that this works. The thing I was missing was that you need the send.py to send a message. If you "execute the function now" in the VSC tool it will just make an HTTP request, which isn't what you want. `send.py` is the way to test your EH function.